# Loop to print iterations separated with a comma, with no comma at the end

Tags: javascript

I'm a student and am writing a JavaScript "for" loop that prints into innerHTML. Every concatenation of the string is added to the last followed by a comma. how do I make it so the comma is not printed after the last iteration? Just for piece of mind, the commas aren't part of the assignment, I'm just trying to add practical application. no jQuery tho please

```
window.onload = function(){
  var mySeven = 0;
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');

  for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++){
      if (i % 7 == 0){
      mySeven += i;
      printSeven.innerHTML += i + ',' + ' ';
      }
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Think about it logically.  How do you know when you are on the last element (hint: `i`)

Comment: Usually you'd just use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on an array…

Comment: @Jonathan, very nice of you to introduce http://www.w3fools.com/ to a student!

Comment: See http://jsperf.com/join-string/ for a few possible approaches

Answer (score 10):

You should use `join()` instead. It's much cleaner and you don't need to worry about edge cases:

```
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');
  var sevens = [];
  for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++){
      if (i % 7 == 0){
        sevens.push(i);
      }
  }
  printSeven.innerText = sevens.join(", ");
```

Or an approach that avoids the `if()` statement and unnecessary iterations:

```
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');
  var sevens = [];
  for (i = 7; i <= 1000; i += 7){
     sevens.push(i);
  }
  printSeven.innerText = sevens.join(", ");
```

And for the sake of understanding, here's how you could do this without `join()`:

```
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');
  var maxValue = 1000;
  var list = "";

  for (i = 7; i <= maxValue; i += 7){
     list += i;
     if(i + 7 <= maxValue){
       list += ", ";
     }
  }
  printSeven.innerText = list;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
 function reorderData(){
   var sevens = Array();
   var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');
   for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++){
     if (i % 7 == 0){
       sevens.push(i);
    }
  }
  var newDisplaySelectedArray = sevens.join(",");
  jQuery( "#multiples_seven" ).val(newDisplaySelectedArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off it is better to not manipulate the DOM inside a loop. You should construct your output in a string or array then add it to the DOM in a single operation :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var mySeven = '';
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');

  for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++){
      if (i % 7 == 0){
        mySeven += i + ', ';
      }
  }
  printSeven.innerHTML += mySeven;
};
```

To delete the trailing comma you have two options : don't add it in the first place or remove it before adding it to the DOM.

Most other answers have concentrated on not adding it, here is a solution which removes it :

```
window.onload = function () {
  var mySeven = '';
  var printSeven = document.getElementById('multiples_seven');

  for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++){
      if (i % 7 == 0){
        mySeven += i + ', ';
      }
  }
  printSeven.innerHTML += mySeven.slice (0, -2);
};
```

A word of caution, if your for loop does not execute at least one iteration you may remove characters you want to display. In the generic case it is easier to build an array and use the `join` function as shown in other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check if you are at the first item than if you are at the last, so simply add the commas before the number:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var mySeven = 0;
  var printSeven = '';

  for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if (i % 7 == 0){
      mySeven += i;
      printSeven += (printSeven.length > 0 ? ', ' : '') + i;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('multiples_seven') += printSeven;
};
```